# How to design underlined custom textbox in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, textbox, uwp-xaml

How can I design an underlined custom textbox in UWP. Example of such textbox is given below -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could set `BorderBrush="Purple"` and `BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"` to change the border color and border thickness directly.

As follows:

```
<TextBox Width="150" Height="40" BorderBrush="Purple" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
     <TextBox.Resources>
        <!-- To also have the focused TextBox only have a border at the bottom, 
             we need to override this resource. -->
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0,0,0,2</Thickness>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Why not set the BorderThickness to `0,0,0,1` instead? That way, you don't need to retemplate the control.

Comment: @chingucoding Yes, you are right, that is more convenient.

Comment: @chingucoding The problem with setting the border thickness to "0,0,0,1" is when you select the textbox the border will appear for left, top, and right as well.

Comment: @RedwanDipto That's a good point, you can change this by overriding the `TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused` resource. I suggested an edit for the proposed solution to include it in the answer.